# Plotting time on x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, seaborn, kdeplot

I'm working with a dataset that only contains datetime objects and I have retrieved the day of the week and reformatted the time in a separate column like this (conversion functions included below):

```
    datetime            day_of_week time_of_day
0   2021-06-13 12:56:16 Sunday      20:00:00
5   2021-06-13 12:56:54 Sunday      20:00:00
6   2021-06-13 12:57:27 Sunday      20:00:00
7   2021-07-16 18:55:42 Friday      20:00:00
8   2021-07-16 18:56:03 Friday      20:00:00
9   2021-06-04 18:42:06 Friday      20:00:00
10  2021-06-04 18:49:05 Friday      20:00:00
11  2021-06-04 18:58:22 Friday      20:00:00
```

What I would like to do is create a `kde` plot with `x-axis = time_of_day` (spanning `00:00:00` to `23:59:59`), `y-axis` to be the count of each `day_of_week` at each hour of the day, and `hue = day_of_week`. In essence, I'd have seven different distributions representing occurrences during each day of the week.

Here's a sample of the data and my code. Any help would be appreciated:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    '2021-06-13 12:56:16',
    '2021-06-13 12:56:16',
    '2021-06-13 12:56:16',
    '2021-06-13 12:56:16',
    '2021-06-13 12:56:54',
    '2021-06-13 12:56:54',
    '2021-06-13 12:57:27',
    '2021-07-16 18:55:42',
    '2021-07-16 18:56:03',
    '2021-06-04 18:42:06',
    '2021-06-04 18:49:05',
    '2021-06-04 18:58:22',
    '2021-06-08 21:31:44',
    '2021-06-09 02:14:30',
    '2021-06-09 02:20:19',
    '2021-06-12 18:05:47',
    '2021-06-15 23:46:41',
    '2021-06-15 23:47:18',
    '2021-06-16 14:19:08',
    '2021-06-17 19:08:17',
    '2021-06-17 22:37:27',
    '2021-06-21 23:31:32',
    '2021-06-23 20:32:09',
    '2021-06-24 16:04:21',
    '2020-05-22 18:29:02',
    '2020-05-22 18:29:02',
    '2020-05-22 18:29:02',
    '2020-05-22 18:29:02',
    '2020-08-31 21:38:07',
    '2020-08-31 21:38:22',
    '2020-08-31 21:38:42',
    '2020-08-31 21:39:03',
], columns=['datetime'])

def convert_date(date):
    return calendar.day_name[date.weekday()]

def convert_hour(time):
    return time[:2]+':00:00'

df['day_of_week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']).apply(convert_date)
df['time_of_day'] = df['datetime'].astype(str).apply(convert_hour)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try:

1. converting the `datetime` column [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)
2. Create a Categorical column from [day_of_week](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.dayofweek.html#pandas-series-dt-dayofweek) [codes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.from_codes.html) (so categorical ordering functions correctly)
3. normalizing the `time_of_day` to a single day (so comparisons function correctly). This makes it seem like all events occurred within the same day making plotting logic much simpler.
4. plot the [kdeplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html)
5. set the xaxis formatter to only display `HH:MM:SS`

```
import calendar

import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, dates as mdates


# df = pd.DataFrame({...})

# Convert to datetime
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
# Create Categorical Column
cat_type = pd.CategoricalDtype(list(calendar.day_name), ordered=True)
df['day_of_week'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(
    df['datetime'].dt.day_of_week, dtype=cat_type
)
# Create Normalized Date Column
df['time_of_day'] = pd.to_datetime('2000-01-01 ' +
                                   df['datetime'].dt.time.astype(str))

# Plot
ax = sns.kdeplot(data=df, x='time_of_day', hue='day_of_week')

# X axis format
ax.set_xlim([pd.to_datetime('2000-01-01 00:00:00'),
             pd.to_datetime('2000-01-01 23:59:59')])
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Note sample size is small here:
[image: kdeplot]

If looking for count on y then maybe [histplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html#seaborn.histplot) is better:

```
ax = sns.histplot(data=df, x='time_of_day', hue='day_of_week')
```

[image: histplot]

Comment: Thanks big time! Would you also happen to know the `return` equivalent for `plt.show()`? I'm returning this plot in a function and `plt.show()` is giving me trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Timestamp` of pandas straight away. By the way your `convert_hour` function seems to do wrong. It gives `time_of_the day` as 20:00:00 for all data.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



sns.set_context("paper", font_scale=2)
sns.set_style('whitegrid')

df['day_of_week'] = df['datetime'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x).day_name())
df['time_of_day'] = df['datetime'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x).hour)

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))

for idx, day in enumerate(days):
    sns.kdeplot(df[df.day_of_week == day]['time_of_day'], label=day)
```

[image: kdeplot]

The kde for wednesday, looks a bit strange because the time varies between 2 and 20, hence the long tail from -20 to 40 in the plot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code and using `df.plot.kde`.

Added more data so that multiple values are present for each `day_of_week` for kde to plot. Simplified the code to remove functions.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    '2020-09-01 16:39:03',
    '2020-09-02 16:39:03',
    '2020-09-03 16:39:03',
    '2020-09-04 16:39:03',
    '2020-09-05 16:39:03',
    '2020-09-06 16:39:03',
    '2020-09-07 16:39:03',
    '2020-09-08 16:39:03',
], columns=['datetime'])
df = pd.concat([df,df1]).reset_index(drop=True)
df['day_of_week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']).dt.day_name()
df['time_of_day'] = df['datetime'].str.split(expand=True)[1].str.split(':',expand=True)[0].astype(int)
df.pivot(columns='day_of_week').time_of_day.plot.kde()
```

Plots:
[image]